# Prevent GetAsyncKeyState() from getting blocked by Antivirus Software

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create an afk money bot for a game.
I'm using `GetAsyncKeyState()` to start and stop the bot.
I've run the code a few times to try out a few things. Then I added a delay between calling the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function using the `clock()` function. When I tried to run the new code, I got an error stating that the .exe file was missing. I tried rebuiding or cleaning the project but it didn't work. Then I deleted the project, created a new one and copied the code back into the project. This did not work either, but I noticed a notification by my antivirus program: The .exe was detected as a *fugrafa* threat. I'm pretty confident that this was somehow caused by the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function since keyloggers can be recognized as a *fugrafa* threat.

There's gotta be a way to prevent this from happening, since I've seen `GetAsyncKeyState()` being used a lot.
Or do I really need to disable the antivirus in order to be able to use `GetAsyncKeyState()`?

Here's the Code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

bool botActive = false;
void timeout(int);

int main()
{
    bool F3_CurrentKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F3);
    bool F3_PreviousKeyState = F3_CurrentKeyState;

    while (true)
    {
        //F3 Key Edge detection
        F3_PreviousKeyState = F3_CurrentKeyState;
        F3_CurrentKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F3);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F3) && (F3_CurrentKeyState != F3_PreviousKeyState)) botActive = !botActive;

        if (botActive)
        {
            std::cout << "Bot Active" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Bot Inactive" << std::endl;
        }
        timeout(100/*ms*/);
    }
}

void timeout(int delay_ms)
{
    clock_t toutStart = clock();
    while (((float)clock() - toutStart) < delay_ms);
}
```

Comment: Assuming you will be the only person using this software, tell your antivirus to exclude your application.

Comment: Or tell the virus scanner to exclude the folders you are building to.  Some virus scanners just trigger on the content of the exe changing.

Comment: You are looking for [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).

Comment: The typical problem with anti-malware is not using a winapi function like GetAsyncKeyState(), it is making an .exe file appearing from seemingly no-where, in an unusual location, to start executing less than a second later.  Focus your energy where it belongs, if you are going to deploy this program on other machines then you'll need a proper installer.

Comment: You might be able to tell it to ignore a directory or something. I had to do this once for something I was working on, although in my case it was removing my object files before the linker even had a chance to run. I was briefly very confused.